# Instr vs InStrRev function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In below example where I use Instr function, it returns 1 as expected.

```
 InStr(1, "rom test", "rom", vbTextCompare)
```

Instead if I use InStrRev function , it returns 0

```
InStrRev("rom test", "rom", vbTextCompare)
```

I am not sure why InStrRev returns 0 instead 1 ? I understand that Instr searches for string starting from left whereas InstrRev searches from right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. The third argument is the start position, not the compare mode. It should be:

```
InStrRev("rom test", "rom", , vbTextCompare)
```

or use named arguments.